# How do I create a function to slice 2d arrays in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

The only user input is the array itself, the first element of the slice and the last element of the slice?

I.e.

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
def slicing_array(array, first_element, last_element):
```

Input:

```
slicing_array(x, 2, 8)
```

Output:

```
[2,3,4,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Some sample inputs and expected outputs would be helpful.

Comment: you could just use slice objects?

Comment: what would expect as the output of the function? Is your problem about accessing a 2D-array?

Comment: The return should be a slice (selected be the user) of a two dimensional array (also selected by the user).

Comment: sill unclear. please write an example

Comment: For example: x=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]), the user inputs slicing_array(x, 2, 8) and the output sould be [2,3,4,6,7,8]

Comment: what would be first_element // last_element. what would you expect as the ouptut? please edit your original post.

Comment: @LucasSchubert, How come 5 is missing?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3, 5, 2], [3, 2, 4]])
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])

def slicing_array(array, first_element, last_element):
    c = len(array[0])
    l = []
    for n in range(first_element, last_element + 1):
            l.append(array[(n-1) // c][(n-1) % c])
    return l

print(slicing_array(a, 2, 4))
print(slicing_array(x, 2, 8))
```

The result is as follows:

```
[5, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: you should mention, that looping over the array using base python syntax instead of relying on compiled numpy functions will lead to performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to using indexing operations on a flattened array

```
a = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
def slicing_array(array, first_element, last_element):
    return array.flatten()[first_element:last_element]

slicing_array(a,2,7)
> array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

numpy has quite the extensive documentation on how you can index arrays:
[numpy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: But would this also work for 2 dimensional arrays?

Comment: missed the 2d part before. flattening the array to a single axis will solve the problem

Comment: your welcome. would you mind marking your question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where to find coordinates of given first and last elements the use you them to find slice like:

```
def slicing_2d_array(arr, first_element, last_element):
    first_coords = np.where(arr == first_element)
    last_coords = np.where(arr == last_element)

    first_x, first_y = first_coords[0][0], first_coords[1][0]
    last_x, last_y = last_coords[0][0], last_coords[1][0]
    
    res = np.vstack(arr[first_x][first_y:last_y+1], arr[first_x+1][first_y:last_y+1])
    for i in range(first_x+1,last_x+1):
        np.vstack([res, arr[i][first_y:last_y+1]])
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you furkan, very kind of you!

Comment: I removed the list comprehension because it adds extra last element. I designed it to return 2d as well (because I just see your expected output).

Answer (score -1):

a = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
def slicing_array(array, first_element, last_element):
return array.flatten()[first_element:last_element]

slicing_array(a,2,7)

> array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])